# Reading a C file line by line where each line has an unknown length

Tags: c, file-io

I am writing a program in C that opens a file and reads in the file line by line performing various actions with each string after it reads in the line.

Now my issue is that I have a loop set up so I read one line in and do the necessary things to that line and then move to the next one until the end of the file. The problem I am having is that I know the maximum line length is 80 characters but it can be less than this so I am having a lot of trouble stopping at the end of the line in order to properly perform the necessary actions.

I would attach code but I am stumped at this part and it is so early that I don't really know if my code would help as it is just at the reading stage. I am unable to figure out how to read in a line when it's length is unknown. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Knowing the maximum line length is extremely helpful. Coupled with [**`fgets()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) it should be fairly straight forward to do what you want. Stopping at the "end of the line" would be looking for either the end of string (null-char) or a newline (`'\n'`), whichever comes first. A fixed buffer of 82 chars would seem large enough (80 chars + newline + terminator),

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the comment and it reinforces what others have said. I had never heard of that method so I can complete my assignment and learn something new!

Answer (score 3):

Define a `char` buffer with a size at least 82 (80 chars + linefeed + null byte).

In a loop, repeatedly call `fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file)` to read one line and perform the tasks until you reach the end of file:

```
char buffer[82];

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file)) {
    /* handle the line in buffer */
    ...
}
```

caution: `buffer` contains a `'\n'` as the last character.

Comment: Is there a way to count the number of characters there is in the line? Also this fgets won't go to the next line?

Comment: Counting the number of characters is easy: `count += strlen(buffer);` inside the `while` loop.  `fgets` reads a new line for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I mean before hand. Is there a way to just read the line of the file before reading it in, like peeking in a stack. If that then I could just adjust the number of chars I read in each time couldn't I?                                                                                                                      As for your buffer there is no way that will go on to the next line? Even if the input string is shorter than 82?

Comment: You do not have to do that: `fgets` reads exactly one line, upto the `'\n'`.  If the lines may be longer than 80 bytes, use a larger buffer or use `getline`.

Comment: fgets() reads **up to** count bytes and stops if line feed are encountered. So no, there is no way, that it will read more than one line in a single call.

Comment: Awesome thank you guys, and then on the next iteration it will move to the next line? or do I need to have something to get it to go past the '\n' ? The line will never be longer than 80 just shorter sometimes.

Comment: @bobHarding , Yes. In the next iteration, the next line is read. Just use the code in this answer and see for yourself!

Comment: `fgets` reads the line **including** the line feed character(s).  A `'\n'` will be present in `buffer` as the last `char` before the `'\0'`, unless the line is longer than 80 bytes before end of line, or there is a missing end of line at the end of file.